# check if a char is a vowel or constant in scheme

Tags: scheme

I am trying to check for a  char is that char is vowel or constant
I don't know what is the problem with my code

```
(display "Please enter a character: ")
(define a (read-line))
(display " ")
(display a)
(newline)
(char? a)
(if (char=? a #\a)
 (display " is a vowel"))
```

Can you help me with it please?

Comment: If this is homework, can you please add the exact instructions? What is the expected result (or output) for a consonant? Also, which dialect of Scheme do you use (eg. Racket, R5RS...)?

Comment: Use the `member?` function with a list of all the vowels.

Comment: `a` is a string, not a character.

Comment: What are the output of your test? You are calling several tests here. Like `(display a)` and `(char? a)`. What are the result? Some of them should have already revealed some problems in your code. I guess you did it to see that, so why don't you tell us what are the result of those tests, and what does it tell you?

Comment: `(list (char? a) (string? a)) ; ==> (#f #t)`

Comment: `(char? a)` does nothing.